# Requesting a node's peers list

Tags: network

When joining the bitcoin network, you request a list of peers that a node has so that you are able to connect to those peers if you wanted to, in order to be better connected. Is there any way that when requesting the peers list of a node, the node could provide a fake peers list with a number of 'bad' nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way that when requesting the peers list of a node, the node could provide a fake peers list with a number of 'bad' nodes?

Certainly. It's impossible to check whether nodes are good or bad without connecting to them. A node can just return whatever IP address and port combinations it wants and the receiver will need to determine for itself whether they are good or bad.